# Open/Closed Subsets of Metric Space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

The problem deals with determining the openness/closedness of the following subsets of the metric space $X$ of all continuous functions from the interval $[0,1]$ to $\Bbb R$, i.e. $X=C([0,1],\Bbb R)$.

$X$ is equipped with the maximum norm, $||f||_\infty$.

The sets $U$ and $V$ are defined as such:

$$U = \left\{ f \in X \middle| \ f\left(\frac 12\right)\lt 5 \right\} $$
$$V = \left\{ f \in X \middle| \ \int_0^1 f(x) \ dx \ge 0 \right\} $$

My guess is that one considers both an open and closed set in $\Bbb R$ and examines the preimage of that set in $[0,1]$. Since $f$ is continuous, if the preimage is open/closed, then the subset (which is simply the direct image under $f$?) is open/closed. Assuming this is the right approach, I do not understand how to choose those arbitrary sets.

Comment: Note that the assignment  $f\mapsto f|_A$ from $C(I,R)$ to $C(A,R)$ is continuous for any subset $A$ of $I$. In particular $C(I,R)\to C(\{1/2\},R)\cong R, f\mapsto f(1/2)$ is continuous. So it suffices to find an open subset of $R$ such that $U$ is its preimage under this restriction mapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not right. What is asked is to say if the sets U and V are either closed or open (or neither) in $(C[0,1],\Vert . \Vert_\infty)$. For $U$, take $f_0 \in U$ and show that the open ball $\{ f: \Vert f-f_0 \Vert_\infty < \epsilon \}$ is in the set for sufficiently small $\epsilon$. Can you conclude? For $V$, consider a converging sequence in $V$ and show that the limit stays in $V$.

Comment: I'll add that $U$ is not closed, since $f \equiv 5$ is a limit of functions in $U$. For $V$, consider the function $f \equiv 0$ and argue that in all of its neighborhoods there are functions with negative measure.

Comment: @roger OK, thank you for the clarification. I thought to start estimating difference between $f$ and $f_0$ by adding and subtracting $f(1/2)$ inside the absolute value and then apply the triangle inequality. Eventually, using the continuity of $f$ and the boundedness of $f(1/2)$ and then taking the supremum, I would arrive at your estimate, or is this again false?

Comment: @Marek Is this a general technique for disproving such arguments for function spaces, meaning, finding one function in the subset that cannot satisfy the conditions for openness/closedness? Is it also necessary to explicitly define the sequence that approaches, for example, $f \equiv 5$ ?

Comment: @Swiftprotector I'm not sure I understand what you mean. A set $U$ is open in $C[0,1]$ is for any element $f_0 \in U$, there exists an open neighborhood of $f_0$ in $U$. For example take $f_0 \in U$ and let $y_0 = f_0(1/2) < 5$. Then the neighborhood $\{ f: \Vert f - f_0 \Vert_\infty < \epsilon \}$ is a subset of $U$ for all $\epsilon < 5 - y_0$.  Indeed, if $f-f_0 < 5 - y_0$, then $f(1/2) < f_0(1/2) + \Vert f - f_0 \Vert_\infty < 5$. You deduce that $U$ is open.